# number validation in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have declared an annotation in my model, for a 10 digit mobile number but it is still accepting more than 10 digits

```
@NotNull
@Min(10)
public String mobileNumber;
```

when we entered any mobile number then accept 10 digit mobile number only

Answer (score 3):

Use `@Size` to define the length of the input.

Use of `@Min` is different.

Also use `@NotBlank` instead of `@NotNull`
as `@NotBlank` will check

- String is not null
- Trimmed length is greater than zero

Answer (score 3):

If you are using hibernate then you can use :

```
@Length(max = 10)
```

to restrict the length of max to 10. This @Length is hibernate specific.
You can also use :

```
@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
```

to set the condition to validate minimum and maximum length as per your requirment.

Answer (score 1):

For mobile numbers validation, I suggest writing your **Custom Validator** annotation. Since mobile numbers can have different valid patterns.
To start, you define an annotation type:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD , ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PhoneNumberValidator.class)

public @interface PhoneNumberValidationAnnotationName {
     String message() default "Message to returned on validation failure";

      Class<?>[] groups() default {} ;

      Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {} ;
}
```

After that, you define your validation logic in a separate class:

```
public class PhoneNumberValidator implements 
      ConstraintValidator<PhoneNumberValidationAnnotationName, String> {

//Here you define your phone number valid pattern
//you can put country code, number length, any specific pattern
private final String PATTERN = "(country-code)[0-9]{8}" ;

@Override
public boolean isValid(String phone, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    
    if(Pattern.matches(FIRST_PATTERN , phone)) {
        return true ;
    }

    return false ;
    
    }   
}
```

For more info, [click here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator)

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work for you

```
@NotBlank(message = "mobileNumber is required")
@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
public String mobileNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

For validating string use `@Pattern` annotation.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{10}$")
public String mobileNumber;
```